# Django 1.9: Image not rendered in template

Tags: python, django, image

I am a django newbie and I am writing a website and trying to upload and image to the About page. The image url seems fine when I right click and view source on the rendered page. but the image does not show up

The following is my code snippet

```
urls.py
-------
urlpatterns = [url(r'^$', views.VBlogIndex.as_view(), name="index"),
url(r'^about/$', views.aboutpage, {'url': '/about/'}, name="about_
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage as FlatPageOrig

class AboutPage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="about")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url
```

about.html

```
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
      <img src="{{ aboutpage.image.url }}"/>
    </div>
    <div>{{ aboutpage.content|markdown }}</div>
```

views.py

```
from . import models
def aboutpage(request, url):
    if not url.startswith('/'):
        url = '/' + url
    site_id = get_current_site(request).id
    try:
        f = get_object_or_404(models.AboutPage,
            url=url, sites=site_id)
    except Http404:
        raise
    template = loader.get_template("static/about.html")
    response = HttpResponse(template.render({'aboutpage': f}, request))
    return response
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/images")

MEDIA_URL = '/static/images/'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

After the page renders the image is not displayed but the following is shown in html source of the rendered page

The django command line says "GET /static/images/about/Dashbox_Asset_Image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1822

Comment: Is there file at `<MEDIA_ROOT>/about/Dashbox_Asset_Image.jpg`?

Comment: Is `/static/images/about/Dashbox_Asset_Image.jpg` the correct location of the image?

Comment: `<img src="{{ flatpage.image.url }}"/>` shouldn't that be `aboutpage`?

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon Sorry I was trying out different names and I missed it.. it is aboutpage.

Comment: @Rohan The image is at the location. I see the image at /static/images/about/Dashbox_Asset_image.jpg

Comment: If the image file is there, then it must be a permissions problem.  Is the image file world-readable, and all directories leading to it?

Comment: Also, the _url_ is `/static/images/about/Dashbox_Asset_Image.jpg`, but that isn't necessarily (and probably isn't) the _filesystem_ location.  According to `settings.py`, the actual filesystem location is `BASE_DIR + static/images/about/Dashbox_Asset_Image.jpg`.  Are you _sure_ the image exists there?

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for helping out. I verified that all the directories leading to the file has drwxrwxr-x and the file also has -rw-rw-r-- .

Comment: the static/images dir is located a folder outside the app(vblog).